# setting jquery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I am trying to use a simple slideshow using jquery [cycle plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) and It dosen't work and I really don't understand what I am missing?

Here is my code:

```
 <script src="js/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
 <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#s2').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollDown',
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            delay: -2000
        });
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
 <style type="text/css">

    .pics {  
    height:  232px;  
    width:   232px;  
    padding: 0;  
    margin:  0;  
    position:absolute;
    left:520px;
    top:120px;
} 

.pics img {  
    padding: 15px;  
    border:  1px solid #ccc;  
    background-color: #eee;  
    width:  200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    top:  0; 
    left: 0 
} 
</style>
```

These are the Images:

```
    <div id="s2" class="pics">
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />

            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />

            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me. see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/BSvNU/)

Comment: That's great and I tried with chrome and firefox but none is working.

Comment: does my jsfiddle work for you? Could you check the console if all file 's are loaded and there are no errors within the console?

Comment: @Manuel I have checked it but wverything is fine I am really getting mad with this It works fine with jsfiddle.

Comment: @sathis I have seen the results and evryhting is looking gud and I don't find any errors.

Comment: @Manuel and I found the error it's with the easing.js script and it's working pretty good now.Thanks for both of you for sorting me out this issue.

Comment: @sathis and I found the error it's with the easing.js script and it's working pretty good now.Thanks for both of you for sorting me out this issue.